# What is the best way to store NodaTime based values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, nodatime

We are implementing PostgreSQL and have also decided to use NodaTime instead of standard .NET DateTime.  PostgreSQL has a "timestamp with time zone" type, and NodaTime returns a Date and time value with a time zone via the SystemClock.Instance.Now method.  However, the value returned by SystemClock.Instance.Now (2015-07-17T13:22:52Z) is not directly writable to the PostgreSQL field.  Is there a best practice for dealing with NodaTime/PostgreSQL implementations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understand, "timestamp with time zone" is a misnomer anyway - it's just "you supply a time zone with a local value, PostgreSQL will store UTC"... in other words, it's really an extra conversion rather than storing more data.

If you're just trying to store an `Instant`, then `timestamp` should be fine as a data type. In terms of getting the value to the database, you should probably just convert it to a `DateTimeOffset`, and let the driver handle that. You'll want to use [`Instant.ToDateTimeOffset`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/NodaTime.Instant.html#NodaTime_Instant_ToDateTimeOffset) when storing, and [`Instant.FromDateTimeOffset`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/NodaTime.Instant.html#NodaTime_Instant_FromDateTimeOffset_System_DateTimeOffset_) when retrieving.

Comment: Thanks, @Jon, you got me on the right track.  Instant does not appear to have a ToDateTimeOffset method (it does have the FromDateTimeOffset method), but SystemClock.Instance.Now.ToDateTimeOffset() did the trick.  I may, however, try to convince the team to just store Instant values.

Comment: @TortillaCurtain: I'm not with you. What makes you think `Instant` doesn't have `ToDateTimeOffset`? How could `SystemClock.Instance.Now.ToDateTimeOffset()` work if it didn't? And what do you mean by "just store `Instant` values?

Comment: I typed `Instant` and tried to type `ToDateTimeOffset` and it didn't show up in the list of methods.  If I forced it by just typing it out like `Instant.ToDateTimeOffset()`, I get an error about accessing a non-static method in a static context.  By storing Instant values, I was thinking about just using a long integer field and storing the raw Ticks value from `Instant`.

Comment: @TortillaCurtain: Yes, it's an instance method - you call it on an `Instant` to convert it to a `DateTimeOffset`. You *could* store the raw ticks, but that would be a pain for anyone else to access - I think a `timestamp` is generally more friendly.

Comment: How about ambiguous times (fall-back transition times in 25-hours days) ? Are they uniquely representable as a DateTimeOffset on DB, with NO collisions?

Comment: @silentman.it: `DateTimeOffset` always represents an unambiguous point in time, precisely because it's got the offset as well as the local time. So when the clocks go back in the UK on Sunday, there'll be 2017-10-29T01:30+01:00 and an hour later there'll be 2017-10-29T01:30+00:00; those are different `DateTimeOffset` values due to the different offsets, even though they have the same local time.